# Github actions: Cloning submodules very slow

Tags: git, github-actions

Cloning submodules is very slow with github actions. Squashing commits has not helped. How to fix this?

Example:

- Log excerpts and details at https://github.com/vishvAsa/purANam/issues/5
- module structure - https://github.com/vishvAsa/purANam/blob/master/.gitmodules
- Github actions yml file [here](https://github.com/vishvAsa/purANam/blob/content/.github/workflows/build.yml)
- Strangely, a different repository (similarly structured, with over twice as many files) is cloned much faster as detailed at https://github.com/vishvAsa/purANam/issues/5 .

Note that submodules are being initialized and updated with

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
git submodule update --remote --merge --recursive
```

Comment: What about [`submodules: recursive`](https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage)? Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I had to squash ALL branches (and ensure that the deploy-branch history does not keep growing over time).​

I could not figure out a way to make sure that submodule initialization/ updation works without peeking into unrelated branches. Trying the below [did not work](https://github.com/vishvAsa/vedAH_sAma/actions/runs/4073130035/jobs/7016681837) (the second command fails with " Unable to find refs/remotes/origin/content revision in submodule path 'content'"):

```
        git submodule update  --single-branch --init --recursive
        git submodule update --remote --merge --recursive
```